# How to Clone fieldset inside of a Cloned fieldset jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, clone

I need to clone a fieldset inside of a cloned fieldset.
[image]

So My regular structure is like

[image]

When I click `add new agenda field` it successfully clones bigger field like

[image]

But when I click `add new file` it only adds new field to parent field not to current field

[image]

My code is like

```
<div id="agenda_placeholder">
    <div id="agenda_template">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Agenda Details</legend>

        <ol>
            <li>
                <label for=topic_name>Topic Name</label>
                <input id=topic_name name=topic_name type=text placeholder="ACAT Briefing" required autofocus>
            </li>
            <li>
                <label for=topic_time>Time</label>
                <input id=topic_time name=topic_time type=text placeholder="2.00 - 2.30 ">
            </li>
            <li>
                <label for=presenter>Presenter</label>
                <input id=presenter name=presenter type=text placeholder="Name LastName">
            </li>


            <li>
            <div id="file_placeholder">
            <div id="file_template">
                <fieldset>
                    <legend>File Details</legend>

                        <ol>
                            <li>
                                    <label for=file_description>File Description</label>
                                    <input id=file_description name=file_description type=file_description placeholder="Ex. Weather Stats">
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                    <label for=file_name>File Name</label>
                                    <input id=file_name name=file_name type=file_name placeholder="Exact file name Eg:weather.docx">
                            </li>
                            </ol>
                        </div> <!-- file_template -->
                     </div> <!-- file_placeholder -->   
                     <button type="button" name="AddNewFile" onclick="Add();">Add New File</button> 
                </fieldset>
            </li>
         </ol>
        </div> <!-- agenda_template -->
    </div> <!-- agenda_placeholder -->
        <button type="button" name="AddNewAgenda" onclick="Add_Agenda();">Add New Agenda Field</button>
    </fieldset>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
        var _counter = 0;
function Add() {
    _counter++;
    var oClone = document.getElementById("file_template").cloneNode(true);


    oClone.id += (_counter + "");
    document.getElementById("file_placeholder").appendChild(oClone);
}

function Add_Agenda() {
    _counter++;
    var oClone = document.getElementById("agenda_template").cloneNode(true);
    oClone.id += (_counter + "");
    document.getElementById("agenda_placeholder").appendChild(oClone);
}
```

So how can I clone a fieldset inside of a cloned field set?

Comment: Yo dawg, we heard you like cloning, but what seems to be the problem?

Comment: I guess because of `div` tag when I click add file it adds file field to only parent fieldset look at the last picture

Comment: Hmm, for starters, the html seems to be invalid. Check out the red tags: http://jsfiddle.net/BQDRJ/

Comment: You are cloning elements which have `id`s.  This is going to cause duplicate `id`s on your page which is invalid.  `id`s should always be unique on a page as they uniquely identify an element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first, your html is invalid it has tags overlapping

in your `add` function the statement
    document.getElementById("file_placeholder")
will return the first match of id `file_placeholder` , and that is incorrect.

what you need is to know which button was clicked and clone its parent div
and append the cloned div to the grandparent div of the button.

the same logic can be applied to `Add_agenda` but you should note to remove added files
to the agenda you are cloning.

```
function Add(btn) {
     _counter++;
    var parentFileTemplate = $(btn).parent("div");
    parentFileTemplate.attr('id',"file_template" + _counter );
    var parentFilePlaceHolder = parentFileTemplate.parent();
    cloned = parentFileTemplate.clone();
    cloned.attr('id',"file_template" + _counter );
    parentFilePlaceHolder.append(cloned);
  }
```

also you must add `this` as parameter when calling the function:

```
<button type="button" name="AddNewFile" onclick="Add();">
```

will be:

```
<button type="button" name="AddNewFile" onclick="Add(this);">
```

Comment: thanks for solution, is there anyway to clone an empty input field though?